# Gtk-WARNING **: 13:51:34.650: cannot open display

Tags: linux, docker, deep-learning

I am running a docker container for a  CV Deep Learning project.
Before running the docker container:

```
$ xhost +
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
```

Now I run my docker container:

```
docker run -it  --gpus all -v $(pwd):/workspace/ xxxxxxxxxxxxx:latest bash
```

Compiled my code successfully and I built my model TRT engine and I am testing it on test.jpg image

```
./demo -e model/centerface.engine -i test.jpg -c test.h264
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(result:30): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:51:34.650: cannot open display: 
(base) root@63c255xxxx:~/TensorRT-CenterNet#
```

Let me know if you guys have an answer, or any guidance it looks more like a linux problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running the container, the following steps are required:

```
sudo xhost +
export DISPLAY=:1
```

then should install the following in the container:

```
apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
```